# JS/TS - function return empty array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function

```
populateGenerals() {

    var generals = [];
    this.productsService.getGenerals()
        .subscribe(data => {
            data.forEach(element => {
                generals.push({ id: element._id, text: element._id });
            });
            console.log(generals);
        });

    console.log(generals);
    return generals;
}
```

inner console gives me:

```
[{"id":"1","text":"red"},{"id":"2","text":"blue"}]
```

while outer console gives me:

```
[]
```

How can I return the same array as inner console when returning *generals*?

**UPDATE / SOLUTION**

```
populateGenerals() {
    this.loading = true;
    var generals = [];


    this.productsService.getGenerals()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.loading = false;
            data.forEach(element => {
                generals.push({ id: element._id, text: element._id });
            });

            this.populateCallback(generals);
        });

    return this.generals;
}

populateCallback(array) {
    this.generals =  array;
}
```

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach` and return that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, map doesn't work. I think because I don't actually map them

Comment: Ah. Is subscribe an asynchronous method?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, no Idea. The reason I said that map is not working, is that I want to assign the `element._id` to both `id` and `name`

Comment: @epascarello, Thanks, but still I really can't get how return the right array using the answer you provided :/

Comment: You can't return it... You need to use a call back or a promise.